Toggle Theme in Django
Lately, whenever I close and reopen my Django project, the admin dashboard consistently displays with the incorrect UI. Initially, it was functioning properly, but later it began to malfunction intermittently.
I've explored various solutions suggested previously, but unfortunately, none have yielded the desired results.
